# Eventbridge Pipe: SQS > EventBus - using sqs message body as event detail

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I have a simple AWS EventBridge pipe: SQS > EventBus

The message body of the SQS message (which is a JSON object) should be the event detail of the EventBus event. But the input template (while working in the AWS console preview) causes the pipe execution to fail. No idea why

My pipe definition in CDK:

```
    new pipes.CfnPipe(this, "pipe", {
      roleArn: pipeRole.roleArn,
      source: queue.queueArn,
      target: eventBus.eventBusArn,
      targetParameters: {
        eventBridgeEventBusParameters: {
          detailType: "FbaNotifcation",
          source: serviceName,
        },
        // omitting inputTemplate will put the entire sqs message (with metadata) under detail.
        inputTemplate: `<$.body>`,
      },
    });
```

So `inputTemplate: <$.body>` does not work (execution fails). Omitting inputTemplate works, but produces a different result. Using `{Payload: <$.body>}` does not work, but also not ideal.

Is it not possible to create a top level object from JSON path with pipes?

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunartely by design.

[*If the original payload is a valid JSON string (for example {"key": "value"}), then use of the input transformer with source specific body data will result in the quotes within the original source payload being removed. For example, {"key": "value"} will become "{key: value}" when delivered to the target. If your target requires valid JSON payloads (for example, EventBridge Lambda or Step Functions), this will cause delivery failure. To have the target receive the original source data without generating invalid JSON, wrap the source body data input transformer in JSON. For example, {"data": <$.data>}.*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-input-transformation.html)

I recommend creating an express step function that does the put events. The task definiton would look like

```json
{
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::events:putEvents",
      "Parameters": {
        "Entries.$": "$"
      },
      "End": true
    }
```

and my input template looks like

```json
{
"DetailType": "DETAIL_TYPE_GOES_HERE",
"Source": "SOURCE_GOES_HERE",
"Detail": <$.body>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar need and noticed using the UI for a transformation suggests a different template:

[image: UITransformer]

```
 targetParameters: {
    // just send the body as a test, nothing else needed here
  inputTemplate: JSON.stringify({
    body: '<$.body>'
  })
```

This also works fine for me via CDK. I expect just sending the body content alone (without the body attribute) ends up not being considered a valid JSON and stops the process as a result.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to extracting the body directly is to rebuild the body using the [Dynamic JSON](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-input-transformation.html#:%7E:text=Dynamic%20JSON) feature of the input transformers.

The key here is that if the original input body was JSON it is parsed by the transformer so it can be accessed via JSONPath for transformations. I guess this is why if you de-reference the body as a value without assigning to a Key in a JSON object it strips out the quotes because these extra quotes would result in an invalid string (not sure why they do not just escape the strings again in this case).

[image]

As an example if the SQS contains the JSON body:

```
{
    "StringValue": "Some String Value",
    "DateString": "2023-12-01",
    "TimeStamp": 1701388800,
    "BooleanValue": true,
    "NumericalValue": 5,
    "DecimalValue": 5.5,
    "ArrayValues": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    "JsonObjects": {
        "IsObject": true,
        "PropertyCount": 2
    }
}
```

It can be passed through as a JSON Object with the input transformer as follows:

```
{
  "StringValue": "<$.body.StringValue>",
  "DateString": "<$.body.DateString>",
  "TimeStamp": <$.body.TimeStamp>,
  "BooleanValue": <$.body.BooleanValue>,
  "NumericalValue": <$.body.NumericalValue>,
  "DecimalValue": <$.body.DecimalValue>,
  "ArrayValues": <$.body.ArrayValues>,
  "JsonObjects": <$.body.JsonObjects>
}
```

**VERY IMPORTANT GOTCHAS FOR NULLABLE/OPTIONAL KEYS**

**ANY KEY** of **ANY TYPE** that is not specifically passed in the JSON Body is assumed to be an empty string `""` instead of `null`.

Any String types you will need to wrap the `Body` value in quotes inside the transformer because Quotes are not added when values are read from the `Body`.

So if the string value could be a a well formed string, empty string or null, then it could result in the following possible outputs when transformed:

- Well formed string:`"My String Value"` -> `"StringValue": "My String Value"`
- Empty String: `""` -> `"StringValue": ""`
- null: `null` -> `"StringValue": "null"`

For Numerical/Boolean/Array/Object types null values work as expected as long as they are either valid values or specifically set to `null`. This is because the `Body` value is not wrapped in quotes in the transformer like has to be done for strings. *Note that empty Array and Objects are valid and work as expected.*

I just encountered this limitation myself and created a SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77609510/aws-sqs-eventbridge-pipe-sns-sqs-looses-json-formating) before I found this one.

After reading the answers by [hb2638](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18766971/hb2638) [kf06925](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3846650/kf06925) and reading the [AWS EventBridge Pipes Input Transformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-input-transformation.html) documentation again for the thousandth time I finally found a workable solution.